# What is (View view) in android?

Tags: android, view

Can anyone please explain why should we use (`View view`), and what does it mean in Android while defining a method.

```
public void dosomething(View view) {}
```

Thanks in advance. I'm a beginner, so my questions might seem basic.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: View is one of the most general class in Android. It holds references to single piece of UI. See link above. Passing View view as argument in methods in most cases gives you opportunity to call method associated with this view. For example if you click on some elements, view is passed in listener so you can know which view was clicked and what attributes it have. Please read Android documentation.

Comment: It's a `View` (or Widget, if you prefer) declared as `View` (the base, unspecialized widget from which all others inherit). And they named it... `view`. Please learn something about Android, before starting to code. You miss the bare basic fundamentals!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually View is used as arguments in methods which act as some kind of listener. 
For example when you have more than 1 `Button` in your layout and you set `onClickListener` on them, you create a method like this:

```
public void onClick(View view){
}
```

Here the View is the view on which the user has clicked. So if you have 2 buttons on your layout, you can check which one the user has clicked by using the following code:

```
public void onClick(View view){
  switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.button1: //do something here
       break;
    case R.id.button2: //do sonething else here
       break;
   }
}
```

Hence, `View` is supplied as an argument when the method is for a listener and the view(Button,Spinner,Switch,etc.) is used to distinguish which view on the layout has been clicked/selected.